# How to pull from a remote branch to my remote branch in git?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git. I have a project that 4 of my friends are starting. We created 4 different remote branch in github for 4 of us. Now, one of my friend created a project in his branch and pushed it in github. My problem is how do i get the project from his remote branch and then transfer into my remote branch to work on it and then push into my remote branch.

4 remote branches.One of my friend created the project in his branch(not the master). I want to get that project from github from his branch to my branch and work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using "git merge", make sure the correct local branch is checked out. Then, to perform the merge, simply specify which branch's commits you want to integrate

step1: suppose your local branch is 'Branch1' first check out your local branch

```
git checkout Branch1
```

step2: merge your friend branch suppose branch is 'Branch2'

```
git merge Branch2
```

Comment: I'd suggest use `git pull` instead of `git merge`. Pull will fetch and merge the changes on remote branch

Comment: Thank you. It works now. And if i want to merge the changes i need to do git add and git commit and git push to my branch right?

Comment: @user11628867 if this solved the issue for you, please accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: @user11628867 you mark above answer as correct by mistake please make sure once.

Answer (score 0):

see if you want to know in which branch you are present just type

```
    git branch
```

you can pull the changes from the required branch only after branch checkout i.e.,

```
    git checkout branch
```

you can pull the changes from other branch by using a command

```
    git pull origin branch
```

And if you want to merge the changes, then first stage the changes that you made and commit and

```
    git push origin branch
```

It makes your changes to be pushed into that branch.

Comment: I tried doing this approach but it did not work whereas the git checkout branch and git merge branch2 works just fine! I could not figure out why your approach did not work.

Comment: I tried pushing it and it works but the pull doesn't seem to work. Thank you so much anyways.

Comment: @user11628867 my answer gives you the result why you didn't mark my answer as correct?? make sure of it.

Comment: @Zaa, git pull can pull the data if not it will do the auto merges.First checkout to your branch and pull the data from the required branch.